# How to initialize C structs with default values

Tags: c, struct, initialization, declaration

I have this defined struct:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct Node {
    int data;
    struct Node* prev;
    struct Node* next;
} Node;

typedef struct List {
    int size = 0;
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tai = NULL;
} List;

List* list1;
```

For the the `node` one it is Ok, but for the `List` one I have a declaration error in visual studio (2022), I am new to C, how to declare default values in C structs?

Comment: There are no default values for types in C. You have to initialize the variables when you define them. (like `List list = {.size=0, .head=NULL, .tail=NULL};`.) For your pointer you need to allocate memory first, anyway.

Comment: Why it's better to use pointer in this case?

Comment: Who said it is better to use pointers? You use pointers if you need pointers. Simple story. Both of your structs use pointers, btw. Your example contains a pointer `List*list1;` that does not point to any valid memory. You can't assign your default values without owning memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C, whether an object is initialized or not depends on how you declare the object, for example whether you declare it as an object of static [storage duration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/storage_duration) (which is initialized to zero unless you explicitly initialize it to something else) or an object of automatic storage duration (which is not initialized, unless you explicitly initialize it).

Therefore, it would not make sense to assign default values to the type definition, because even if the language allowed this, it would not guarantee that the object of that type will be initialized.

However, you can create your own function which initializes your `struct` to specific values:

```
void init_list( List *p )
{
    p->size = 0;
    p->head = NULL;
    p->tail = NULL;
}
```

Assuming that the object is declared inside a function (not at [file scope](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/scope)), you can use the following code to declare and initialize the object to default values:

```
List list1;
init_list( &list1 );
```

If the object is declared at file scope, you can't call the function `init_list` at file scope, but you can call the function inside the function `main`, for example.

Alternatively, when you declare the object, you can also initialize the individual members:

```
List list1 = { 0, NULL, NULL };
```

This will also work at file scope.

Since everything is being initialized to zero, it is sufficient to write the following:

```
List list1 = { 0 };
```

In that case, all members that are not explicitly assigned a value will be initialized to zero.

Answer (score 1):

In C opposite to C++ you may not initialize data members in structure declarations like you are doing

```
typedef struct List {
    int size = 0;
    Node* head = NULL;
    Node* tai = NULL;
} List;
```

Also it does not make sense to declare the global pointer `list1`.

```
List* list1;
```

What you need is to write

```
typedef struct List {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail; // I think you mean `tail` instead of `tai`
} List;

int main( void )
{
    List list1 = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };
    //...;
```

Answer (score 1):

In C you can't define a `struct` with default values for the members.

You *can* however create a global instance with the default values set that you then use for initialization. That's pretty common in the C world.

Example:

```c
typedef struct List {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
} List;

// The init-value to use
const List List_INIT = {.size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL};

int main() {
    List l = List_INIT; // using the init-value
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typedef struct List {
    int size;
    Node* head;
    Node* tail;
} List;
```

What you have defined here is a new data type, you haven't declared any variables of such a type. The name `List` is not a variable, it is the name of a structure type. The names `size`, `head` and `tail` are not variables, they're the identifiers for the members of this `struct`.

> How to declare default values in C structs?

You can not define a type with default value for the members. Simply provide a definition for it with/after declaration:

```
List apple;
memset (&apple, 0x00, sizeof apple);

/* Or */

List apple = { .size = 0, .head = NULL, .tail = NULL };

/* Or */

List apple = { .size = 0, .head = 0, .tail = 0 };

/* Or */ 

List mango = { 0, NULL, NULL };

/* Or */

List banana = { 0, 0, 0};

/* Or */

List orange = { 0 };¹
```

[1] — §6.7.9 Initialization:

> If there are fewer initializers in a brace-enclosed list than there
> are elements or members of an aggregate, or fewer characters in a
> string literal used to initialize an array of known size than there
> are elements in the array, the remainder of the aggregate shall be
> initialized implicitly the same as objects that have static storage
> duration